# What helps store the inputted data on a backend page in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, web-services

So I am new to web development and all I've learnt so far is how to write HTML and CSS to make web pages and forms.

I'm specifically looking for a language that will help me store the data that is input into the form onto a database for easy access later.

I think PHP does that, but I was looking for anything JAVA related, and somewhere I could learn how to do it.

So far,
I've looked into JavaScript tutorial on W3Schools, but it seems like JS only helps make the front end more dynamic, but doesn't help store the input data anywhere.

I've also looked into the AngularJS tutorial on CodeSchool and it looks like Angular helps present the forms in a better manner and again, not in storing data anywhere.

Once again,

1) What do you use to collect the data input into a HTML form and store it somewhere?

2) I don't need help making the actual form itself.

Comment: database, or localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Me personally, i use PHP, it allows you to take the data that was inputted and store it in a database. You can also use JavaScript/JQuery with PHP via Ajax that will dynamically fetch and store data.

Comment: Do you know any source on the net where I could learn how to do this?

Comment: You can use http://www.w3schools.com/php/ - they have alot of tutorials!

Comment: Does a Java servlet help you do somethong similar?

Comment: From Googling Java Servlet, i believe so, but ive personally not used it yet, so i wouldn't be able to offer advice.

Comment: If you want to go with PHP than vue.js framework is really good for client side and laravel is very good php framework (Laravel and Vue JS: Advanced Frontend Webapp Architecture).

Answer (score 1):

Any backend lang can do it (python, php, java, ruby, js with node), but each one has it own ways to do it. Even JS at client side can do it, using LocalStorage objects, but it not solve all problems at data storage yet.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is just the client-side. You will need a server, which will handle the requests and store them into a database. I would work with Spring Boot (JAVA) on the server side, and Angular 2 on the client side. Use REST for the communication bewtween them. Its really not hard.

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js** is a fast Javascript runtime combined with a low-level API similar to the standard libraries of many programming languages (file system access, buffers, streams, i/o, etc.).

**Angular** is a model-view-controller framework for client-side JS development. It can be used with Node.js as a backend, or anything else. Its main feature is 2-way data-binding, and addresses most of the concerns of a single-page web app within the framework.

**React** is often compared to Angular, because it is a front-end library, but it is not a framework. It is simply the view layer, with a large ecosystem of open-source projects supporting it. The big conceptual difference is a uni-directional data flow, rather than 2-way data binding. You need a lot more besides React to make a full application, but React handles it's use case exceptionally well. React is amazing on the client side, but it’s ability to be rendered on the server side makes it truly special. This is because React uses a virtual DOM instead of the real one, and allows us to render our components to markup. Node.js makes a great backend for React as well, but again, it can work with any backend.

The **MEAN stack** is a popular web development stack made up of MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js. MEAN has gained popularity because it allows developers to program in JavaScript on both the client and the server. The MEAN stack enables a perfect harmony of JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) development: MongoDB stores data in a JSON-like format, Express and Node.js facilitate easy JSON query creation, and AngularJS allows the client to seamlessly send and receive JSON documents.

MEAN is generally used to create browser-based web applications because AngularJS (client-side) and Express (server-side) are both frameworks for web apps. Another compelling use case for MEAN is the development of RESTful API servers. Creating RESTful API servers has become an increasingly important and common development task, as applications increasingly need to gracefully support a variety of end-user devices, such as mobile phones and tablets.

This was the overview of all the new booming technologies.. Based on this you can decide what you need and what you want to learn.. Thanks, Hope this overview helps you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite for Rest Api is Flask(python micro framework) it is build for create Rest Api. and for php falcon has it own micro frame work. if you use nodejs it is easy to communicate between backend and frontend and good with not sql dB like mongo db.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer should be the database or localStorage/sessionStorage.

The decision in between which answer chose, depends if you want to share the data between Browsers/Computers or if you just want to temporarily store the data for the user so he won't need to fill the form once again.

For temporarily storage chose localStorage/sessionStorage (javascript).

For other cases chose to store the data in a Database.